# My computer is suddenly powers off and restarts

Tags: windows-7

My computer suddenly powers off and restarts. It can happen at any time. Sometimes it occurs one minute after booting and others after hours or days or even a week.

I have checked my ram, hard disks, and OS and have found nothing. I have coolermaster650w smps, core i7, rampage3gene main board, AMD HD5770gpu, 8GB RAM.

What else can I do / check for?

Comment: Have you checked for heating problems?

Answer (score 4):

Random power offs like that can often be due to a bad or insufficient power supply.  If you have another power supply handy try using it.  If you have a different, preferably older, graphics card, put it in and see if the computer still reboots.  Modern 3D graphics cards draw a lot of power.